# Java using array[] to assign to next index

Tags: java, arrays

So I know that Java treats arrays' sizes as immutable, but in other languages like PHP, I have been able to use `[]` to assign a value to the next index of an array:

#### PHP:

```
$arr = array();

//Arr looks like this
$arr => {}

$arr[] = "Value";

//Arr looks like this
$arr => {"Value"}
```

Is there a similar function in Java?

```
int[] arr = new int[0];
arr[] = 3;
arr[] = 4;

//arr => [3, 4];
```

Comment: Java arrays are not immutable, but they cannot be resized.  You need `ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: I'm familiar with ArrayList, I just wanted to know if there is a dynamic workaround to creating a new array every time you want to change the size. Oh and I meant the size is immutable, not the whole object :P

Comment: @David The _"dynamic workaround to creating a new array every time you want to change the size"_ is called `ArrayList`, in which you can preallocate however much space you want and let the library manage it for you.

Comment: @David: So you're saying, "I know you can't change the size, but is there any way for me to change the size?"? What?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java you have to set the size of the Array when you create it

```
int[] arr = new int[2];
```

Then once the array is created, you can add values to a specific index like this:

```
arr[0] = 3;
arr[1] = 4;
//Now arr = {3, 4}
```

However, you cannot add a third value to the array `arr` because the size is fixed at 2. If you need to change the size of the array, an `ArrayList` would be better. You can just use the `add()` method and it will add values to the end of the array

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arr.add(3);
arr.add(4);
arr.add(5);
//Now arr contains the values {3, 4, 5}
//You can continue you add values
```

EDIT: Another option is to use the [Arrays.copyOf(int[] arr, int size)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

```
int[] arr = {3, 4};
//arr contains the values {3, 4}
int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 4);
//arr2 contains the values {3, 4, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Ok so there is **no** way to change the size dynamically. I'd have to recreate the entire array each time I wanted to add a new index?

Comment: Yes. You can create a method that does that for you, but you would have to iterate through your entire array and add each value to your new, bigger array.

Comment: @David ArrayList does not recreate the entire array every time. It internally manages an array that is bigger than the logical capacity of the list, so that it has room to grow. It recreates the array only when needed.

Comment: @mdewitt Exactly what I wanted to know! Thanks so much! +1/accept

Comment: I think, you could also use Arrays.copyOf(...) to create a bigger array.

Comment: @David I added Arrays.copyOf(...) to my answer for you

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, Java arrays cannot be resized. However, if you used `ArrayList<Integer>`, you could use the `add()` function to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

no. you have to use your own index or use an `ArrayList` and the `add` method

Answer (score 0):

Almost. There is a shorthand syntax for array creation:

```
int[] arr = {3, 4};
```

Otherwise use a List which resizes automatically:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
// etc
```

Comment: What's not useful about this answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have to set the number of elements in the array when you construct it.  So you can't append more elements to the end of an array.

You can do the following to move to the next element in the array:

```
int[] arr = new int[2];
int = 0;
arr[i++] = 3;
arr[i++] = 4;
```

That works because `i` is incremented after each array element is assigned.

If you really want to append to the end of a list, you should use a Java collection class.  Unfortunately you can't have a collection of primitive types (like `int`).